# Python Fabric, how run sudo find --exec commands

Tags: python, fabric

I am running Fabric 2.6.0, and trying to execute a command on a list of remote servers.  I've gotten connected to the system and able to perform sudo commands.  I want to perform `find {dir} -name \'*cleanup*\' -exec rm -fr {}\;` where the variable `dir` is a directory I'm passing in.  I'm using command `ls -ltr` in it's place to not be destructive.

So I have a command `c.sudo(f"find {dir} -name \'*cleanup*\' -exec ls -ltr \{\} \;")`
the {} so f-string doesn't try to interpret them.  This fails saying f-string expression cannot include a backslash.

I've also tried looking around on overflow and tried adding a variable `backslash_char ='\\'` which changed my line to `c.sudo(f"find {dir} -name \'*cleanup*\' -exec ls -ltr {backslash_char}{{backslash_char}} {backslash_char}\;")`
But this returns with Find: missing argument to '-exec'

What is the proper way to perform a sudo find  -name '*file*' -exec ls -ltr {} ;

Thank you!